# How do i print the number of records in each partition from RDD

Tags: python, bigdata, rdd

The data set is big so `.glom()` and `.collect()` cannot be used. I have created a hash partition, I am just looking to print the number of records in each partition. I can use `.glom()` but not `.collect()` for some reason?

Answer (score 0):

`rdd.glom().count()` will give the number of partitions.